# Html document not downloading from google search url

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, httpclient

I used this below code from to download html content from google search url

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#q=chiranjeevi+movies");
var sdata = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

When i inspect on browse i find "klitem" class with div tag, but when read my response it is not showing, i don't no why it's not showing when i download the url content, any one please help me...

Comment: Maybe the tag is created dynamically via javascript?

Answer (score 0):

> When I inspect on browser I find "klitem" class with div tag, but when read my response it is not showing, I don't no why it's not showing when I download the url content.

When you inspect on browser, you can find some HTML elements. Actually, they are elements in a DOM tree rendered by the web browser. They are not in the response content.

If you look at the **Network tool** of the develop tool, you will find when you call your url, the browser will send several requests and in the first request, it returns a html page like following
[image]

And this is the same content that read from your response. Unlike web browser, `HttpClient` can only get the response from one request. We can not get the final DOM tree from it. Google won't return the search result directly. As @Mehrzad said, the final result is possibly created dynamically via JavaScript. If you check the **Network tool**, you can find there are a lot of JavaScript requests in them instead of a static page.

Comment: Zuo is there any way to get that html content..?

Comment: @DeviPrasad I'm not sure what html content you want to get. You can try with this url: `https://www.google.co.in/search?q=chiranjeevi+movies` to get the html page returned by Google. However, this html page also contains a lot of JavaScript codes. It's not a static page, you may not get the html elements you want. One possible way to get the rendered DOM tree is using `WebView` control to load the page first and then invoking with script to get the content like in [my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574852/uwp-webview-get-links-from-webpage-into-an-array).